# is it a O(n) or what time complexity? i am using searching for a value inside the loop (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using only one loop here but inside the loop there is an condition
 "if target not in seen" so i am checking target value is available in seen set .Is this also need to check for time complexity.Then what is the time complexity for the below?/

```
def makepair(arr,val):
    if len(arr)<2:
        return "Not enough data"
    seen=set()
    output=set()

    for v in arr: #o(n)
        target = val - v
        if target not in seen: # is it included
            seen.add(v)
        else:
            output.add((min(v,target),max(v,target)))
    return output 
makepair([1,2,3,4,5,6],4)
```

Comment: `set` lookup is O(1) so if you traverse the list only once, it's O(n)

Comment: I'm not clear on why you need two sets here, though. Why do you need "seen", why not just create a set of tuples? It automatically removes duplicates.

Comment: Actually, are you trying to do some time-series-esque stuff? You know that sets are unordered in Python 2.7? It looks like you want to take snapshots of the running min/max as you traverse the list, but all your results will be jumbled at the end because the `output` set will not maintain any order.

Comment: @roganjosh set is unordered in both python2 and python3

Comment: @Gahan fair enough, the dictionary ordering doesn't carry over to sets, but it doesn't change any of my points. It's a decent correction on what I implied, thanks.

Comment: set lookup is o(1) that is confusing me . on the worst case the value i am searching it will traverse the whole set . why it is not another o(n)? @roganjosh

Comment: @roganjosh i need seen to track  the already taken value

Comment: @user9580899 Sets are hash tables, not just duplicate-free lists.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is O(n) because you're only traversing the list once.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is O(N). You make a single pass on the list; this means that each item of the list must be checked against the `set` once, and once only. Set lookups are O(1); you can see time complexities [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

A set stores hashes of the values. When you check for membership, the value you are looking for is first hashed and then it is known (almost) *exactly* where that value would be in the set *if it actually is part of the collection*. In that case, it's little different than check for equality i.e. `== 5`. I say "almost" because there can be hash collisions, but that's something you should look into yourself on how they are resolved.

The downside of the lookup efficiency is that sets are not ordered in Python. Your code looks like you want to maintain some kind of order.